# OAuth authorize endpoint returns invalid_request in ASP NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin

I am building an ASP.NET Web API that needs to support logins from 3rd party clients. The 1st party logins are working and authenticated requests can be made to my API endpoints.

However, when I try to call my /oauth2/authorize endpoint to generate a bearer token for the 3rd party client, I cannot get it to work.

[image: Authorization request]

My OAuth provider looks like this:
[image]

My configuration looks like this:
[image: App configuration]

Answer (score 0):

Try to call context.Validate() in AuthorizeEndPoint method.